# How to reach inactive activity from active activity?

Tags: android, layout

Assume that, there are two activities called A and B and

A: active activity, (user can see layout)

B: inactive activity (can't see)

But i want to reach inactive activity from my active activity. Inactive activity has a chronometer and some strings. Layouts must be nested.

does chronometer work if i reach to it?

[image: diagram]

Comment: What do you mean by reaching to inactive activity? To do what? If your just gonna set something try to use static, but carefully. Or give more info ?

Comment: Or why not you put those into one activity, and set their visibility?

Comment: naturally timer is not static. I only wonder how to create nested layouts

Comment: I think you would be better off using `Fragment`s here.

Comment: @OlegVaskevich can you give an example, link etc?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html